# Query to identify the number of revisions made to a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there any query which can return me the number of revisions made to the structure of a database table?

Secondly, how can I determine the number of pages (in terms of size) present in mdf or ldf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get last modify date or creation date of object in `SQL Server`.

For examle info on tables:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='U'
```

[More info on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

Number of pages can be fetched from `sys.database_files`.

[Check documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a `trigger` and store all changes to the table in a separate table. You can then use this table to get the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` doesn't keep track of changes so it can't tell you this.

The only way you may be able to do this is if you had a copy of all the scripts applied to the database.

In order to be able to capture this information in the future you should look at `DDL triggers (v2005+)` which will enable you to record changes.